# OSX 10.11.1 - KeyChain access does not allow change to access permission

Tags: macos, xcode, keychain, keychain-access

In **Keychain Access** I would like to add **Xcode** to my the list of applications allowed to access a password.

I opened KeyChain Access on category *Passwords*, double-clicked the password I want to have the **Access Control** changed, switched to that tab and added **Xcode** in the list.

When I hit **Save Changes**, a modal window appears stating

```
Keychain access wants to change access permissions of the "the.key.com" item in your keychain
```

I have to enter my Keychain password, then hit one of three buttons: *allow*, *deny* or *allways allow*.

When clicking *allow* or *allways allow* nothing happens. The only option to dismiss the modal window is to click *deny*.

Same behaviour when I open a project using the password in **Xcode**. I get the same dialog with the same issue.

I did try the usual tricks like restarting, changing password, fixing permissions with DiskUtil and also searched a little bit, but [the only thing I found](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26476) does not fit to my issue as Xcode is not running.

---

Update: The complete login Keychain is affected, I can not make changes to any password

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: See my own answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was introduced by **OSX Serve**r and the user _**xcsbuildd** and the related user folder setup that can not be handled by **Keychain**.
File access rights are so messed up that I will reinstall **OSX**.

---

**Edit:**
Reinstall probably was unnessecary.
Although some access rights can no longer be altered in Keychain Access, there are fields for these in Xcode preferences and in some hidden options in OSX Server.

Comment: Hi @dogsgod I am having the same problem with the modal window, do you have an idea how I can fix this without re-installing the OS?

Comment: Use the IDE Apple decided to be responsible for this specific key. In my case it has been Xcode - changing account data in Xcode works fine, Keychain still refuses to update the key. I also had to learn, that editing over a VNC connection might not work (see other answer here), but it does work with direct access to the machine ...

Comment: brilliant thanks alot, this was it! I was using my mac remotely, when I tried it locally it finally worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using VPN or any sort of software that's simulating mouse movements? See here:

"code sign wants to sign using key - Doesn't allow or always allow but deny works" https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25092

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I use a utility called MagicPrefs that changes my mouse behavior. Once I quit it and restarted XCode, I was able to allow access to the key.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if you have gone through some of these steps.

1. Attempt to repair the keychain.
2. If you're willing create and new keychain
3. Delete the keychain preferences folder in the Library and see if that helps.

Comment: Yep, tried it all